# Checking Response header in groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to test the response header contain X-Duration-MS text.  I'm pretty sure The way I'm checking assert is missing main check if the X-Duration-MS is not on the header.  Can you please help me to test it right way?

This is my code:

```
    def httpResponseHeaders = context.testCase.testSteps["Testname"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders
    //log.info (httpResponseHeaders)
    httpResponseHeaders.each
    {
      k,v ->
        if(k=~"X-Duration-MS"){
          assert k == "X-Duration-MS"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Using groovy Script

You are checking that there is one `X-Duration-MS` response header despite its value. Then you can use `keySet()` function on `httpResponseHeaders` to get all the http header names, and then use `contains()` to check that your desired header is in the list. So you can try with:

```
def httpResponseHeaders = context.testCase.testSteps["Testname"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders
assert httpResponseHeaders.keySet().contains("X-Duration-MS")
```

#### Using Script Assertion

You can also achieve your goal using `Script assertion` in your request instead of a `Groovy` testStep. In your request UI in the down left corner there is an `Assertion(0)` text, click on it and then use the `+` button in the Assertion panel to add an `Script Assertion`. Then inside this script you can do the same are you doing in the *Groovy* testStep without the need to find the testStep to get the response because in the `Script Assertion` there is the `messageExchange` object in the context which you can use to get the details for the current request, response, http headers... So there you can simply use:

```
def httpResponseHeaders = messageExchange.getResponseHeaders() 
assert httpResponseHeaders.keySet().contains("X-Duration-MS")
```

[image]